# Displaying employee record or manager record along with his employees in oracle apex report

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have created a report with a form in Oracle Apex where:

- if normal employee logins in timesheet application, then the report should display only the employee record, but
- if manager logs in then the report should display manager record along with all the employees working under him.

How to achieve this? can anyone guide me?

[image]

Comment: Could provide some examples of what you have tried so far?

Comment: 1.first I have written function in SQL developer tool to find manager id and his employee id:  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION CALLING_FUNCTION_IN_APEX(
      loggedInUserId IN Number)
   RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
AS
   c_direct_reports SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN

   OPEN c_direct_reports FOR SELECT DISTINCT e1.SUPERVISOR_ID,e1.emp_ID
                          
          FROM   TIMESHEET_EMPLOYEES e1 INNER
          JOIN TIMESHEET_EMPLOYEES e2
          ON e1.SUPERVISOR_ID = e2.emp_id AND e2.name!=e1.name AND e1.SUPERVISOR_ID=loggedInUserId;

   RETURN c_direct_reports;
END;

Comment: Then  in oracle apex plsql function body I have written plsql code for pageitem and pageitem value I have passed to report   declare loggedInUserId NUMBER;
BEGIN
    select count(*) into loggedInUserId from TIMESHEET_EMPLOYEES where UPPER(EMAIL_ID)=UPPER(v('APP_USER'));
    IF loggedInUserId > 0 THEN    
        select distinct EMP_ID INTO loggedInUserId from TIMESHEET_EMPLOYEES where UPPER(EMAIL_ID)=UPPER(v('APP_USER'));
    END IF;
;    return loggedInUserId;
END

Answer (score 0):

How do you distinguish "normal employees" from "managers"? There should be some table which says so. As code you posted as comments (really, why did you do that? Couldn't you edit the question and post properly formatted code instead of this unreadable mess?) suggests that unique identifier is someone's e-mail address which is also used as username when logging to Apex, that table would have pairs [e-mail + role], e.g.

```
SQL> desc apex_roles
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ------------------------
 E_MAIL                                             VARCHAR2(15)
 ROLE                                               CHAR(1)

SQL> select * from apex_roles;

E_MAIL          R
--------------- -
lf@gmail.com    M          --> M = manager
kamal@yahoo.com E

SQL>
```

Now, create a function which says whether someone is a manager. Let it return `1` if it is, `0` if it is not (why not Boolean? You can't use it in `select` statements).

```
SQL> create or replace function f_is_manager(par_app_user in varchar2)
  2    return number
  3  is
  4    retval number := 0;
  5  begin
  6    select 1
  7      into retval
  8      from apex_roles
  9      where e_mail = par_app_user
 10        and role = 'M';
 11
 12    return retval;
 13  exception
 14    when no_data_found then
 15      -- user isn't a manager
 16      return retval;
 17  end;
 18  /

Function created.

SQL>
```

Now use that function in `where` clause in report; suppose that this is table that contains data you'd like to display:

```
SQL> select * from my_data;

E_MAIL               JOB              SAL
-------------------- --------- ----------
CLARK@gmail.com      MANAGER         2450
KING@gmail.com       PRESIDENT       5000
MILLER@gmail.com     CLERK           1300
lf@gmail.com         MANAGER         2200        --> manager in APEX_ROLES table
kamal@yahoo.com      CLERK           1500
```

What happens when kamal runs the report? That user sees only its own data:

```
SQL> select job, sal
  2  from my_data
  3  where e_mail = case when f_is_manager('&&APP_USER') = 1 then e_mail
  4                      else '&&APP_USER'
  5                 end;
Enter value for app_user: kamal@yahoo.com

JOB              SAL
--------- ----------
CLERK           1500
```

But, if a manager runs it, it sees everyone's data:

```
SQL> select job, sal
  2  from my_data
  3  where e_mail = case when f_is_manager('&&APP_USER') = 1 then e_mail
  4                      else '&&APP_USER'
  5                 end;
Enter value for app_user: lf@gmail.com

JOB              SAL
--------- ----------
MANAGER         2450
PRESIDENT       5000
CLERK           1300
MANAGER         2200
CLERK           1500

SQL>
```

---

As it is Apex, you'd actually use

```
select job, sal
from my_data
where e_mail = case when f_is_manager(:APP_USER) = 1 then e_mail
                    else ':APP_USER'
               end;
```